# Is it possible to import numpy to Python 3.9 from Anaconda?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have a question about using numpy library.
A couple of months ago, I downloaded Anaconda, which gives numpy automatically.
I am trying to use numpy by importing from ANaconda to Python.
WHat I have done is:
I added the package of numpy from Anaconda folder to Python folder.
However, the python shell says that

```
  File "C:\Users\Alice Jun\Desktop\Python 3.9\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\Alice Jun\Desktop\Python 3.9\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\Alice Jun\Desktop\Python 3.9\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Alice Jun\Desktop\Python 3.9\gui.py", line 2, in <module>
        import numpy as np
      File "C:\Users\Alice Jun\Desktop\Python 3.9\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
        from . import core
      File "C:\Users\Alice Jun\Desktop\Python 3.9\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
```

What should I do to import numpy?
Thank you and stay safe!

Comment: Did you activate the conda environment? Also, can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "I added the package of numpy from Anaconda folder to Python folder. "

Comment: Have you included the line: `import numpy as np` in your code ?

Comment: Also, your folder structure looks pretty odd -- you have the numpy package in the `Desktop\Python 3.9\numpy`. Although technically not wrong (if setup correctly), it looks hella odd. Did you just copy the package from the conda folder to your local folder? If so -- this is not the way to do it

Comment: Diagnosis steps: 1) activate a conda environment (**Anaconda Prompt** on Start menu); 2) type `conda list numpy` (should return a version); 3) type `python`, 4) at python's `>>>` prompt, type `import numpy as np`. Likely you will get an error somewhere, and that will help identify what needs to be done to fix the error.

Comment: @RafazZ Yes. I just copied and pasted the numpy folder from the conda folder to my local folder.

Comment: @Shivam Roy Yes. I typed import numpy as np

Comment: Oh this is not right -- don't copy the packages from where you installed them to to a local folder. There is a reason why we do either `conda install numpy` or `pip install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, that is not a proper way of installing a package. You are making a copy anyway, so install it through proper routes, e.g.,

```bash
# where `python` is the one you wish to use
python -m pip install numpy
```

Otherwise, the reason why what OP shows did not work is because packages are located under a `site-packages` directory (search under your `Python 3.9/` directory. If one really wants to manually install a package, that's where it goes.

However, be aware that Conda packages make heavy use of dynamic linking in order to minimize redundancy of common dependencies. This is often done through @rpath specifications, which means moving packages out of their Conda environment path will frequently result in non-functionality.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am bit confused still. 
Where should I type "python -m pip install numpy?

Comment: I typed "python -m pip install numpy" in the Command Prompt, I received
"Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-pacakages (1.19.2)"

Comment: @Bora that sounds like your Conda environment is on PATH. If you wish to use a different Python, you need to ensure it is the only one on PATH (check with `where python` or `which python`). When in shell, Conda's Python can be removed by running `conda deactivate`.